# Create an enum set of generic type

Tags: java, generics, enums

How can I create an empty [EnumSet](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/EnumSet.html) when I don't have the runtime type of the generic enum? Example code:

```
public class Utility<T extends Enum<T>> {
    private T[] enumConstants;
    public Utility(Class<T> e) {
        enumConstants = e.getEnumConstants();
    }
    private EnumSet<T> emptyEnumSet() {
        // ?
    }
}
```

Here's my current workaround, I think it comes a bit clumsy:

```
private EnumSet<T> emptyEnumSet() {
    T first = enumConstants[0];
    EnumSet<T> result = EnumSet.of(first);
    result.remove(first);
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`EnumSet.noneOf()` should do what you need. Your code receives the `Class<T>` as the constructor parameter, so you'd need to store it in a field.

Comment: Ooh, I think I got confused with my generic type arguments. It does work indeed.